# AppBarLayout leaves a white band at the bottom of the screen while scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using this layout trying to achieve a collapsable app bar.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_contacts"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

It works fine but while scrolling it leaves a white band at the bottom of the screen. I've posted an image to make it more clear.
[Bottom ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l10VL.png)

Any ideas how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put viewPager outside of AppBarLayout and inside coordinatorLayout

Comment: Tried it but now the screen is empty and when scrolling instead of the white gap I see the recyclerView.

Comment: Thanks did not work at first because of a typo but now works as it should. Thanks a lot.

Comment: enjoy coding and drink tea !!